# Visualize dependencies within module in a repository

Tags: visual-studio

I have a large repository and I will need some visualization to get a high-level picture of the project. [Dependency Cruiser Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=juanallo.vscode-dependency-cruiser) is what I need but somehow isn't working. Are there any similar VS Code extensions?